# Sorting algorithm that depends on initial organization of data

Tags: sorting, data-structures

I am presently studying sorting algorithms. I have studied that quick sort algorithm depends on the initial organization of data. If the array is sorted, quick sort becomes slower. Is there any other sort which depends on the initial organization of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Insertion sort will be O(n) with the descending sorted input:

```
define selection_sort (arr):
  out = []
  while not (arr.is_empty()):
      x = arr.pop()
      out = insert x out
  return out
```

because each `insert` call will be O(1). If `pop_last()` is used instead of `pop()` then it will be fastest on the sorted ascending input (this assumes `pop()` and/or `pop_last()` are O(1) themselves).

Comment: The optimized Bubblesort also depends on the initial data state (it hard stops whenever no swaps were made in one of the rounds).

Answer (score 0):

All fast sort algorithms minimize comparison and move operations. Minimizing move operations is dependent on the initial element ordering. I'm assuming you mean initial element ordering by initial organization.

Additionally, the fastest real world algorithms exploit [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) which which also shows dependence on the initial ordering.

If you are only interestend in a dependency that slows or speeds up the sorting dramatically, for example bubble sort will complete in one pass on sorted data.

Finally, many sort algorithms have average time complexity O(N log N) but worst case complexity O(N^2). What this means is that there exist specific inputs (e.g. sorted or reverse sorted) for these O(N^2) algorithms that provoke the bad run time behaviour. Some [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) versions are example of these algorithms.

Comment: "many sort algorithms have average time complexity O(N log N) but worst case complexity O(N^2)" - if you're just talking about variations of quick-sort, I wouldn't call these different algorithms, rather just variations of the same algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

If what you're asking is "should I be worried about which sorting algorithm should I pick on a case basis?", unless you're processing thousands of millions of operations, the short answer is "no". Most of the times quicksort will be just fine (quicksort with a calculated pivot, like Java's).

In general cases, quicksort is good enough.

On the other hand, If your system is always expecting the source data in a consistent initial sorted way, and you need long CPU time and power each time, then you should definitely find the right algorithm for that corner case.

Comment: I am asking a off topic question. Is the quicksort is best among all the sorting algorithms for the large input size

Comment: That's clearly not what the question is asking.